# Scrolling left while making website RTL on just one page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, overflow, right-to-left

I am developing a website and i am making it RTL. the whole website is ok but i have a problem on 1 page

I am having trouble on making [this](https://nicvo.com/business-listing/) page RTL.

Since other pages are ok, i am pretty sure the search form on this page is making this problem. even i used the following code to avoid scrolling but after clicking on search fields, the pages scrolls left again:

```
html, body {overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue. I don't see any scrolling to the left.

Comment: Hi Thanks for helpin. check it now. please click on the search fields bellow the map. when you click on them, page scrolls to left. i have this problem only on this page: https://nicvo.com/business-listing/          because of search form. I think the horizontal scroll is hidden but if you use mac, you can scroll to left by using the mouse. if you want to see it, you can click on the search fields

Comment: I think i found a way to solve this problem. I changed the body direction to LTR while my website language is RTL. I am using wordpress and editor for righting is still RTL while my theme is LTR. I will test it and if i get success, i will write the results of my changes here to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have discovered the problem. You have the following CSS declaration:

```
.single.options-hidden.selectator_element .selectator_input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

That **left: -10000px;** seems to be the cause of your issue.